# What does "extra shiny" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> The brass ring to reach for is extra shiny, as the long-term target
>   environment will be dynamic, efficient and programmable.

I searched, and found out that brass ring is an expression for some kind of goal. Then, what does "extra shiny" mean? Does "The brass ring to reach for is extra shiny" mean that "the goal will be extra valuable"?

I couldn't find the source. It's been a long time that I read this line from a paper.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation being the most logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely meaning of this phrase is, as you guessed, that the goal is more attractive or desirable. In addition to it's literal meaning, "shiny" is often used to imply that something is valuable or desirable. Thus, a brass ring (as you note, a goal) being extra shiny means it is more desirable or more valuable.